# How do I make HTTP::Daemon::SSL work without certificates?

Tags: perl, network-programming

I downloaded [HTTP::Daemon::SSL](http://p3rl.org/HTTP%3a%3aDaemon%3a%3aSSL) for Strawberry Perl 5.10 from CPAN and ran this example:

```
use HTTP::Daemon::SSL;
use HTTP::Status;

# Make sure you have a certs/ directory with "server-cert.pem"
# and "server-key.pem" in it before running this!
my $d = HTTP::Daemon::SSL->new || die;
print "Please contact me at: <URL:", $d->url, ">\n";
while (my $c = $d->accept) {
    while (my $r = $c->get_request) {
        if ($r->method eq 'GET' and $r->url->path eq "/dir") {
            # remember, this is *not* recommened practice :-)
            $c->send_file_response("f.html");
        } else {
            $c->send_error(RC_FORBIDDEN);
        }
    }
    $c->close;
    undef($c);
}
```

The application died on this line:

```
my $d = HTTP::Daemon::SSL->new || die;
```

I don't have certificates. Is there an option to customize this code to run it without the need of certificates? If yes, could someone help with this?

I also tried to replace

```
my $d = HTTP::Daemon::SSL->new || die
```

with

```
my $d = HTTP::Daemon::SSL->new(SSL_use_cert => 0) || die;
```

and got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Simply create some dummy keys and certificates for testing.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/en/ssl/ssl_faq.html#selfcert

Comment: I generated some certifactes for testing as on the link you mentioned but still die .